# use a for in a variable in host_vars/group_vars

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to minimize my efforts when adding content to my hosts/vars groups.

For example, I have a variable that looks like this:

```
blue_items:

- name: ocean
  color: blue
- name: sky
  color: blue
- name: umbrella
  color: blue
```

result with a debug:

```
root@debian:/opt/ansible# ansible -m "debug msg=\"{{blue_items}}\"" client1 client1 | SUCCESS => {     "msg": [         {             "color": "blue",             "name": "ocean"         },         {             "color": "blue",             "name": "sky"         },         {             "color": "blue",             "name": "umbrella"         }     ] }
```

I tried to use a "for" parsing into a list:

my host_vars:

```
list_blue_items: \['ocean', 'sky', 'umbrella'\]

blue_items:
{% for item in list_blue_items %}

- name: "{{ item }}"
  color: blue
  {% endfor %}
```

result with a debug:

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
found character that cannot start any token

The error appears to be in '/opt/ansible/host_vars/client1/nginx.yml': line 4, column 2, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

blue_items:
{% for item in list_blue_items %}
^ here
```

I also tried adding a pipe in front of the variable like this :

```
list_blue_items: \['ocean', 'sky', 'umbrella'\]

blue_items: |
{% for item in list_blue_items %}

- name: "{{ item }}"
  color: blue
  {% endfor %}
```

But the result isn't like i want, all the content is written on a single line and don't return my items:

```
client1 | SUCCESS => {     "msg": "- name: \"ocean\"\n  color: blue\n- name: \"sky\"\n  color: blue\n- name: \"umbrella\"\n  color: blue\n" }
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, given the data in *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/colors.yml
data:
  blue: [ocean, sky, umbrella]
  green: [grass, peas, car]
  red: [flag, apple, hat]
```

Use *set_fact* and create the variables

```yaml
- set_fact:
    "{{ item }}_items": "{{ dict(data[item]|product([item]))|
                            dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='color') }}"
  loop: "{{ data.keys() }}"
```

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: |
      {{ item }}:
        {{ lookup('vars', item,  default='[]')|to_nice_yaml(indent=2)|indent(2) }}
  loop: "{{ q('varnames', '.*_items') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [host_A] => (item=blue_items) => 
  msg: |-
    blue_items:
      - color: blue
        name: ocean
      - color: blue
        name: sky
      - color: blue
        name: umbrella
ok: [host_A] => (item=green_items) => 
  msg: |-
    green_items:
      - color: green
        name: grass
      - color: green
        name: peas
      - color: green
        name: car
ok: [host_A] => (item=red_items) => 
  msg: |-
    red_items:
      - color: red
        name: flag
      - color: red
        name: apple
      - color: red
        name: hat
```

---

There are plenty of other options on how to use the data:

- Use Jinja if you want the *for* loop

```yaml
blue_items: |
  {% filter from_yaml %}
  {% for i in data.blue %}
  - {name: {{ i }}, color: blue}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfilter %}
```

gives what you want

```yaml
blue_items:
  - color: blue
    name: ocean
  - color: blue
    name: sky
  - color: blue
    name: umbrella
```

- Optionally, you can use the filter *product* and create a dictionary first

```yaml
blue_items: "{{ dict(data.blue|product(['blue'])) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
blue_items:
  ocean: blue
  sky: blue
  umbrella: blue
```

If you need the list of the dictionaries use the filter *dict2items*

```yaml
blue_items: "{{ dict(data.blue|product(['blue']))|
                dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='color') }}"
```

also gives what you want

```yaml
blue_items:
  - color: blue
    name: ocean
  - color: blue
    name: sky
  - color: blue
    name: umbrella
```

---

Example of a complete project for testing

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/colors.yml
data:
  blue: [ocean, sky, umbrella]
  green: [grass, peas, car]
  red: [flag, apple, hat]

blue_items: "{{ dict(data.blue|product(['blue'])) }}"

blue_item2: "{{ dict(data.blue|product(['blue']))|
                dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='color') }}"

blue_item3: |
  {% filter from_yaml %}
  {% for i in data.blue %}
  - {name: {{ i }}, color: blue}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfilter %}
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: blue_items
    - debug:
        var: blue_item2
    - debug:
        var: blue_item3
```

---

There are plenty of other options on how to use the data. For example, declare *color_items*

```yaml
color_items: "{{ dict(data[color]|product([color])) }}"
```

and use it in the tasks

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: color_items
      vars:
        color: blue
```

gives

```yaml
  color_items:
    ocean: blue
    sky: blue
    umbrella: blue
```

Use the dictionary in a loop

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ color_items|dict2items }}"
      vars:
        color: blue
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [host_A] => (item={'key': 'ocean', 'value': 'blue'}) => 
  msg:
    key: ocean
    value: blue
ok: [host_A] => (item={'key': 'sky', 'value': 'blue'}) => 
  msg:
    key: sky
    value: blue
ok: [host_A] => (item={'key': 'umbrella', 'value': 'blue'}) => 
  msg:
    key: umbrella
    value: blue
```

If you use *item* in the declaration instead of *color*

```yaml
color_items: "{{ dict(data[item]|product([item])) }}"
```

you can iterate the colors

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ color_items }}"
      loop: "{{ data.keys() }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [host_A] => (item=blue) => 
  msg:
    ocean: blue
    sky: blue
    umbrella: blue
ok: [host_A] => (item=green) => 
  msg:
    car: green
    grass: green
    peas: green
ok: [host_A] => (item=red) => 
  msg:
    apple: red
    flag: red
    hat: red
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded in creating a new variable:

```
nginx__vhost_list:
  - vhost1.test.com
  - vhost2.test.com

nginx__vhost: |
  {% for vhost in nginx__vhost_list %}
  - name: "{{ vhost }}"
    file_conf: "{{ vhost }}.conf"
    name: option1, option2
    tls: "/etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ vhost }}.key"
  {% endfor %}

nginx__vhost_final:
  "{{ nginx__vhost | from_yaml }}"
```

Wouldn't it be possible to keep only my "nginx__vhost" and my list, I don't think it's a good way to create a variable just to filter another one, I'd rather be able to filter directly on the 1st variable.

Comment: Please do not ask new questions in an answer. In that case ask a new question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).